# How can you take several hundred screenshots with Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, screenshot, puppeteer

I have a folder with several hundred html files. I need to take screenshots of each one and I thought I could use Puppeteer in my Gulp task.

```
function takeScreenshots() {
    return gulp.src(path.join(paths.dest.stage, "**/*.html"))
        .pipe(tap(async (file) => {
            const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
            const page = await browser.newPage();
            await page.setViewport({
                width: 1024,
                height: 768,
                deviceScaleFactor: 1,
            });
            await page.goto("file://" + file.path);
            await page.screenshot({ path: path.join(path.dirname(file.path), path.basename(file.basename, ".html") + ".jpg"), quality: 10 });
            await browser.close();
        }));
}
```

When I run this, my computer's fan goes on, things lock up, and I get this message:

```
(node:85389) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 exit listeners added to [process]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

I think it's trying to do all of the screenshots at the same time but I don't know how to tell it to take one, finish, then move onto the next one and etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a quick search but didn't found any way to synchronous pipes.so I wrote a workaround.

1- first thing you will add all files to "files" array using pipe & gulp-tap

2- then subscribe at "end" event

3- then write your business logic which depends on files array

```
function takeScreenshots() {
  const files = [];
  return gulp
    .src(path.join(paths.dest.stage, "**/*.html"))
    .pipe(
      tap((file) => {
        files.push(file);
      })
    )
    .on("end", async () => {
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      await page.setViewport({
        width: 1024,
        height: 768,
        deviceScaleFactor: 1,
      });

      for (let i = 0, len = files.length; i < len; i++) {
        const file = files[i];
        await page.goto("file://" + file.path);
        await page.screenshot({
          path: path.join(
            path.dirname(file.path),
            path.basename(file.basename, ".html") + ".jpg"
          ),
          quality: 10,
        });
      }

      await browser.close();
    });
}
```

Comment: I ran your code but I got the following: (node:86106) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Protocol error (Page.navigate): Session closed. Most likely the page has been closed.

Comment: This error because the browser closed after first screenshot. i fixed it. run it and tell me if everything is good